# DatabaseError when Login Out of Application

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm working on a project that consist on sensor data and realtime database data into the application. My App receives the data from the sensor every time it is updated, using a StreamBuilder. Everything is working fine, I can get, update, add and remove data from my database, I can login and register succesfully. But I'm having problems when Logging out of my Application. Every time I log out, I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred.
DatabaseError (DatabaseError(1, com.firebase, Permission Denied))
```

The Error comes from this function, from the "await for":

```
// Função para ler o valor da temperatura
  Stream<int> getSensorTemperature() async* {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

    await for(var event in databaseReference.child(user.uid+"/temperature").onValue) {
      yield event.snapshot.value;
    }
  }
```

I have a similar function under this one, but doens't show any errors:

```
Stream<int> getSensorHumidity() async* {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

    await for(var event in databaseReference.child(user.uid+"/humidity").onValue) {
      yield event.snapshot.value;
    }
  }
```

This is my Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write":"auth != null"
  }
}
```

This Error only occurs when logging out, I know this has to do with my security rules, But My app crashes every time I log out, how can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules currently require that a user must be signed in at the time your app reads or writes anywhere in the database.  That's why you're getting an error.

You have two choices.  Either change the rules to allow permission even if there is not a user signed, or change the logic of your code to only read and write when there is a user sign in.

I suggest you do the latter, as leaving your database open to writes without requiring a sign-in could lead to security problems in your app.

You can read more about security rules in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Comment: I'm have created the rules that way because of security, my App is basically complete, but I can see and error in this, because If I log out I wasn't suppose to get this error, since I'm not even in the main page where this code makes effect.

Comment: So, as I recommended, don't query the database if there is no user signed in.  Ask them to sign in again first.

Comment: Yes, But how is it querying the database, if this function is not being called from out of the main menu.

Comment: I don't know - you're going to have debug this.  If you have specific code that isn't working the way you expect, please ask a new question and show your debugging details that illustrates what's not working the way you expect.  There needs to be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.  Note that currentUser can be null, which means no user is signed in.

Comment: My answer is suggesting you can do whatever you want, as long as you "change the logic of your code to only read and write when there is a user sign in.".  Whether you do that with an if statement or something else doesn't really matter.  There are lots of ways to solve this.